# Error 500 in IBM Notes Client 9.0.1

Tags: xpages, lotus, ssjs

I am facing issue (Error:500 Unexpected run time error ) in some cases when xpages based application is opened in Note 9.0.1 client. This issue is not reproduce because when you restart your client it automatically resolve the problem and its not come very often.

Initially we were using Server 8.5.3 but we have upgraded server to 9.0.1 FP4HF71. We have not observed this issue on 8.5.X clients.

Can anybody tell why this issue sometime occur on some machine and automatically issue is fixed when machine re-starts .

Anybody else facing same issue or not? Possible solution?

It works well other than xpages apps.

Thanks,
Qaiser

Answer (score 2):

Is this while you're developing? If you make a change in Domino Designer and want to see the change in XPiNC, you need to close Notes and re-open. It's to do with how the applications are loaded and how the XPages runtime differs in XPiNC vs server. (My guess is that the XPiNC XPages runtime uses the .class files for the application loaded in memory, but building the application recreates those - it has to - so the files are no longer available for the XPiNC runtime.)

There's no way round it and my recommendation (and what I've used for XPiNC development on other projects) is develop and test in Firefox, then do a final review in XPiNC when complete. Troubleshooting in Firefox is significantly easier than XPiNC, even with Firebug Lite plugin, so it will be an easier development experience.

The biggest single different with XPiNC look and feel / processing is if `@DbLookup` and `@DbColumn` are coded with "" as the first parameter, which works on browser but is bad practice. Following best practice of using `@DbName()` as the first parameter will yield consistent results on XPiNC and browser.

It won't occur for non-XPages applications, because they are the only applications using the XPages runtime built into the Notes Client for XPiNC.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. No, These are old applications running well in 8.5.X environment but sometime same application opening in Notes Client 9.0.1 throw this error (NOT ALWAYS) same client work well 100 times but at one time it create issue and no issue found on web client.

Comment: I'd check workspace logs (Help > Support > View Log / View Trace) for more information. Also, if the application doesn't have an error page, it's worth adding one, so you can capture what the specific error is.

Comment: 9.0.1 added specific settings for allowing Java code in Notes Preferences. I'm not certain that's a factor here, because it would always fail for users who had not ticked that setting. But it's a difference between 8.5.3 XPiNC and 9.0.1 XPiNC

Comment: I really appreciate quick response. This error is not logged on server log.nsf and moreover this error is not related to code. Only thing which I can think is time out on client side? if application is not loaded in specified time? because next time you restart your client it works perfectly fine. Moreover I will go through log as if issue occurred again. How can I translate message?

Comment: Unless you're running the application in XPiNC as "Run on server", any errors will certainly be logged in the Notes Client logs and not the server. Even if you're using "Run on server" it may still be logging to the local logs.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the port under Preferences -> Domino Designer -> Web Preview Port to 8080 or something along those lines. Maybe port 80 is already in use.